# How to configure Javac plugin in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac

I run a custom compiler plugin with the `-Xplugin:MyPlugin` switch, which injects some extra methods into my classes. I set the additional command line parameters under

`Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler` -> `Java Compiler`

Everything builds just fine, but in the IDEA editor every call of the generated methods is highlighted red, and also autocomplete does not work.

What else can I configure to make it recognize the generated methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA to make it aware of the methods you generate. On-the-fly code analysis in IntelliJ IDEA uses its own parser and reference resolution implementation; it does not use javac, and cannot be extended by writing javac plugins.

The main entry point for such a plugin is the [PsiAugmentProvider](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-psi-api/src/com/intellij/psi/augment/PsiAugmentProvider.java) class.